# executing a SCUFL xml in Taverna Workbench

Tags: taverna

I am relatively new to the workflow management system and was exploring taverna. I understand Taverna workbench is a GUI for building and editing workflows, but if I have a SCUFL xml which is the underlying language that the graphical workflow represents, then is there a provision in the taverna workbench that allows me to directly import and execute the given XML ?.

Or is this something that i must do with the taverna command line tool?, I tried to find this in the documentation but could not find a reference.